# Samba between 2 ubuntu systems is one-way only

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

I am having a problem with my samba configuration.

I have an ubuntu system, let's name it A, that had ubuntu 16.04 until recently and now has ubuntu 20.04. This A computer was connected to a second one, let's name it B, with ubuntu 18.04, via samba (among other ways) to copy files between those systems.

I had several folders in each system and everything worked fine while in 16.04

After the format and the transition to ubuntu 20.04 the connection is now one-way only. More specifically, B cannot see any folder in A anymore. The folders appear shared in Files though. On the other hand, when accessing the shared folders in B from A everything works fine. I have tried some solutions but nothing seems to solve my problem (obviously I am missing something here).

In my samba conf file (`/etc/samba/smb.cfg`) for example, in both systems, I have this on  my [global] section

```
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   client min protocol = NT1
   server min protocol = NT1
```

which was the solution proposed at a question. It helped me to not get an actual error when accessing my shared folder from B but it does not actually display any shared folder (there is just an empty folder).

My final attempt was the instructions using from this [site](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-quick-and-easy-file-sharing-with-samba/):

where an anonymous share was (theoretically) being shared by adding:

```
[Anonymous]

path = /samba/anonymous
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
force user = nobody
```

under the `#======================= Share Definitions =======================` in A system only.

This created a folder, named `Anonymous`, when viewed from B in shared folders but I cannot really access it. It requires a password but it does not take any. Neither samba nor the user password. Anyway, it points to a non existing folder in my system (I have tried with an existing one nothing changes) but it doesn't seem so handy if I have to apply this for every shared folder.

So, does anyone have any idea how to properly share some folder between 2 ubuntu systems?
As far as I know samba and samba client are installed on both systems.

Edit (after some comment request from @Morbious1):

```
$testparm -s

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    client min protocol = NT1
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server min protocol = NT1
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    usershare owner only = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[Anonymous]
    force user = nobody
    path = /home/gorfanidis/share_testing
    read only = No


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

and

```
$net usershare info --long

[python_projects]
path=/home/xxxx/python_projects
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y

[misc_cerberus]
path=/home/xxxx/misc
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y

[EfficientDet]
path=/home/xxxx/python_projects/EfficientDet
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=n

[surveillance object detection]
path=/home/xxxx/Datasets/surveillance object detection
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=n
```

Comment: -This created a folder, named Anonymous,- It created a share of that name because you told it to. The name of the last segment in your question [Anonymous]. If you change that name it will change the share that is seen.

Comment: Yeah, I get that it's named after that [Anonymous] tag but this only refers to how it will be displayed the folder name. It doesn't affect its contents.

Comment: That is not an anonymous share. It specifically requires a credentialed user to gain access. Plus since there is a force user added to the share definition even a credentialed user would be denied access unless the permissions on the /samba/anonymous folder was set to owner = nobody. It's a very bad Samba Howto. Why not post the output of the following commands to your question: `testparm -s` and `net usershare info --long`

Comment: @Morbius1 it certainly feels like a credentiated shared folder. I have added the output of the commands you mentioned.

Comment: There is noting wrong with your samba usershares as long as that users home directory isn't encrypted. For your [Anonymous] share change your force user to: `force user = gorfanidis` and allow guest access by adding `guest ok = yes` And don't forget to restart smbd after editing smb.conf: `sudo service smbd restart`

Comment: ok this seems to work. But it's a step back from making it work automatically from Files (nautilus). Is there a way to achieve this? Also, if you want to make it an answer I could accept it if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HowTo you followed said that this share definition allows guest access:

> ```
> [Anonymous]
>     force user = nobody
>     path = /home/gorfanidis/share_testing
>     read only = No
> ```

It does the opposite.

To make it guest accessible and to make sure there are no Linux permissions issues I would suggest the following changes:

```
[Anonymous]
    force user = gorfanidis
    path = /home/gorfanidis/share_testing
    read only = No
    guest ok = yes
```

> ok this seems to work. But it's a step back from making it work
> automatically from Files (nautilus). Is there a way to achieve this?

If this is a single user system what you could do is add `force user = gorfanidis` to the [global] section of smb.conf - right under **workgroup = WORKGROUP** is where I would put it. Then it would apply to all shares you create regardless of how you create them.